# opencv QRCodeDetector throw Exception?

Tags: c++, opencv, qr-code

I am writing a C++ program to test on reading QRCode, and here is my very little code fragment:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::imread("fail.png");
cv::QRCodeDetector d;
std::vector<cv::Point> ps;
d.detect(m, ps);
if (ps.size() > 0) {
    std::cout << d.decode(m, ps) << std::endl;
}
```

I try to test it using the image below:

[image]

And I got exception on d.decode(), anyone have idea to avoid such a case?

Environment:
Visual Studio 2015, Opencv 4.0.0

Comment: *what* exception did you get? I would also suggest updating your OpenCV to the latest version. 4.0.0 is two years old and there have been many bugfixes and improvements since then.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF86152ED29 (ntdll.dll) in barcode-main.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x00007FF8615987F0).


Will try to update the opencv later.

Comment: Okay on opencv version 4.5.0, but need to use detectAndDecode() to detect the qrcode, and using decode() after detect() return an empty string

Comment: no idea what's up. can't reproduce. this should be working as far as I can see. this works just fine on my old 4.1.1 setup (in python but that's the same). `points` shows me four corners. decoding gives me the string `WeCanOverCome.` and the matrix of code bits. try using a `Mat` instead of `vector`. maybe it's bothered by that.

Comment: Don't know why, but anyway thanks Christoph.

Comment: please *try* the suggestion of a different type

Answer (score 2):

I just reproduced this behavior in C++, with types for the corner points:

- `std::vector<cv::Point>` which is integer
- `std::vector<cv::Point2d>` which is floating point (double)
- `cv::Mat` which gets its type assigned by `detect()` to fit

it fails for the integer Point, works for the other two.

it might be a bug, or just a failure of documentation. feel free to post minimal complete reproducing code and data to [OpenCV's github issues](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues?q=qrcodedetector)